# How to add IP whitelist in an HTTP API?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I want to add the feature of allowing only some IP addresses(list would be given already) to access my HTTP API, written with DJango and Django Rest Framework.

Comment: use kong for better management.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use a firewall of the operating system(or higher layer).